# Multiselect JS not able to send data to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

I am using [Multiselect JS](http://loudev.com/#home). I want to pass selected multiselect values to jquery but I am not able to get the values.

#### HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="{{filter.title}}" id="multiselect_to_1" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">

    </select>
</div>
```

#### jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $("#multiselect_to_1").val();
    console.log(dt);
    //this prints null on console
```

When I try from F12 console I am able to get those values. But not on form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var $select = $("#multiselect_to_1");

   // via the plugin on changes
   $select.multiselect({
       afterSelect: function(values) {
          console.log(values);
       }
   });

   // old skool
   console.log(
     $select.find('option:selected')
       .map(function() { return this.value; })
       .get()
   );

   // if you want the array to be displayed as a string
   var someArray = ["value 1", "value 2"];
   console.log('as string with .join: ', someArray.join(', '));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` to get element by id: `var dt = $("#multiselect_to_1").val()`;

So jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $("#multiselect_to_1").val();
    console.log(dt);
    //this prints null on console
```

More about CSS selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp